# AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior not working in Wicket 8

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I'm switching from Wicket 6 to Wicket 8, and `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` doesn't seem to work anymore.

Example page:

```java
    public HomePage() {
        final Form<Void> form = new Form<>("form");
        final TextField<String> txt = new TextField<>("txt", new Model<>());
        txt.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void onUpdate(final AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                System.out.println("update: " + txt.getValue());
            }
        });
        form.add(txt);
        add(form);
    }
```

and corresponding html:

```html
<form wicket:id="form">
<input wicket:id="txt">
</form>
```

In Wicket 8.5.0, the `onUpdate` method never gets called, and there is no error message. In Wicket 6 it works fine. The same thing happens with other component types, e.g. select/DropDownChoice.

Is this a bug? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What if you try replacing `onchange` with `change`? I seem to vaguely recall something about the event names no longer needing a prefix, but I'm not sure which Wicket version introduced this change

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke hmm, you're right, it seems to work with `change` in both versions. You should probably post this as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The events prefixed with `on` have been deprecated since Wicket 6. In Wicket 8, support for them has been removed. You can get these components to work again by changing `onchange` to `change`.

See also: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migration+to+Wicket+8.0